# Struts2.3 resource not found

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts

This is my first project in Struts. And when I run this project I get the error:

```
"The requested resource is not available."
```

This is what I have done:

I am using Struts 2.3.15. This is what my project structure is: [project structure](http://postimg.org/image/ieuqyntbl/).

**This is the `index.jsp` page:**

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
   <form action="hello">
    <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/>
   </form>
   </body>
  </html>
```

**This is `struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts> 
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
 <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="hello" 
       class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction" 
       method="execute">
       <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
       </action>
 </package>
</struts>
```

**This is `web.xml` file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
  </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**This is `HelloWorld.jsp`:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title> 
</head>
 <body>
   Hello World, <s:property value="name"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

**This is `HelloWorldAction.jsp`:**

```
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;
public class HelloWorldAction{
private String name;
  public String execute() throws Exception {
     return "success";
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

And one more thing that I have done is I copy pasted all the libraries from extracted struts folder to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

What I am missing out and what's the problem here?

Comment: What Url do you enter the browser?

Comment: The `FilterDispatcher` is deprecated since Struts 2.1.3.

Comment: The url that i am entering is:  http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldStruts2/index.jsp

Comment: Even after using org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter instead of FilterDispatcher , the problem is still present.

Comment: show, what files you have under `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: @Jaiwo99: i have copied all the .jar files that i downloaded from struts site. The list is very big so cant't post it's pic.

Comment: at least you have to post exception tracestack here

Comment: @user1788048 You must *not* randomly deploy "every jar in the download"; in this case you're missing some (or all) dependencies required by the plugins you're not actually using (GXP). Please consider using a dependency management tool instead of just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got solution to your problem, you need add this to the config file `struts.xml` which should be on classpath when you run your web application.

```
<action name="index">
    <result>/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

try

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldStruts2/index.action
```

Comment: still getting this error:There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path [/HelloWorldStruts2].

description The requested resource is not available

Comment: really? did you forget to put struts.xml to the web-inf/classes?

Comment: action name should be `index` this error doesn't use my answer settings.

Comment: yes it's there only.Now i am getting error as resource not available.

Comment: then put resource to the webcontent folder and remove <welcome> files from `web.xml`.

Comment: I mean the resource is index.jsp.

Comment: to get it working after changes you need to clean, rebuild, redeploy, restart.

Comment: Finally it worked... Thanks a lot. By the way, i don't have any idea about what is maven and why is it used for?If i use maven then will i not face problem of dependencies?

Comment: maven dependencies are preconfigured by the software engineers and stored in the repository far away from your eyes. If you use maven you should not face the problem with *incorrect* dependencies.

Comment: there's eclipse plugin for maven called m2eclipse or m2e, that have a UI that helps to simplify the maven tasks while configuring and running your project with maven.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the stack trace, it is not an answer of your question, so you should NOT put it as an answer, the reason you got this error is, you have too many jars copied into your ´WEB-INF/lib´, just remove all the plugins you don't need, there is the similar problem: [Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970879/struts2-tutorial-doesnt-work), it could also be the solution for you

Comment: Now I have added only the required jars. But Now i am getting this error when i run the project:There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path [/HelloWorldStruts2]

Comment: @user1788048 try localhost:8080/HelloWorldStruts2/hello.action, btw, you should set a string to the var ´name´, so it can be shown on the page

Comment: i was looking over here which has same error as that of me:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991597/struts-hello-world-example-there-is-no-action-mapped-for-namespace-and-act  , i changed my struts.xml position as i am not using maaven, still it's giving the same error. And i tried the url you gave but it show's the webpage cannot be displayed

Comment: @user1788048 You'd better use maven to resolve dependencies issue if you can't manage them manually. Different versions of libraries might have incompatibility issues that leads to incorrect behavior and error prone.

Comment: @user1788048 seems you need add     <action name="/">
    <result>/index.jsp</result>
  </action>    to your struts.xml and call HelloWorldStruts2/